# GET Request - Why is my URI so long?

Tags: ajax, get, request, parse-platform

I'm making a GET request using the PARSE API.  I'm getting a "414 Request-URI Too Large" error, but I don't understand why.  Here is the code for my request:

```
 $.ajax({ 
      url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats',
      type : 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data : JSON.stringify({   
        order: '-createdAt',    
      }),
      success : function(data) {
        handleData(data)
      },
      error : function(data) {
        console.log('error: ' + data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: That error is coming from the backend; your example creates the url `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?{%22order%22:%22-createdAt%22}`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not following.  What do you mean by the error is coming from the backend?

Comment: `414 Request-URI Too Large` is the [response code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) from the server. Specifically, you're sending too much data in request; and the server is telling you to use a `POST` and will not allow you to use `GET`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's what I don't understand, how I could be sending too much data in the request.  Also, despite the error, the function containing the GET request seems to be working fine.

Comment: What do you see on the console? Specifically, a line starting 'error:'.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The console displays "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " and provides the 'too long' URL.  When you follow the URL, you come to the 414 Error.

Comment: Add a [try catch](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml). Your actual problem isn't visible here.

Comment: Added a try/catch, but the catch isn't throwing an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the server says so, e.g. the service you're querying against is so configured. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)

`414 Request-URI Too Long`
The URI provided was too long for the server to process - [The HTTP/1.1 Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). Often the result of too much data being encoded as a query-string of a GET request, in which case it should be converted to a POST request.