# Sending payload in GET request's body instead of POST to resolve HTTP 414 URI Too Long

Tags: json, ajax, http, get, server-side

A 414 error is caused by a long URI parameters on a GET request. It has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157706/get-request-why-is-my-uri-so-long) to use a POST request in that case, however, wouldn't it be more realistic to send the data in the GET request's body, even though it is [not recommended to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319813/call-http-get-with-json-body-content-parameters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to send data in the `GET` request's body. According to [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Thus, it's not "more realistic", but actually less realistic, as some browser or server may reject such HTTP request.